# Multilingual speech synthesis

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to choose a speech synthesis voice for a specific application culture? The application has 4 cultures (CultureInfo) for changing localization (translation): Russian, Ukrainian, German and English, as well as speech synthesis (System.Speech).

The problem is that the Russian text is voiced without any problems, and, for example, the English word Exit, instead of the usual "exit" is voiced as "exit".

I tried like this:

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-US") {
      speechSynthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));    
      speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync(Sys.Header.ToString()); 
} else if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "de-DE") {    
      speechSynthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));    
      speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync(Sys.Header.ToString()); 
} else if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "ru-RU") {    
      speechSynthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"));    
      speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync(Sys.Header.ToString()); 
} else { speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync(Sys.Header.ToString()); }
```

but this does not work; the switch-case construction also does not give results(

P.S. Sys in the code above is a menu item (MenuItem).

Comment: The if statements seem entirely redundant. You could simply call `speechSynthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` followed by `speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync(Sys.Header.ToString())`.

Comment: Also note the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoicebyhints?view=netframework-4.8#system-speech-synthesis-speechsynthesizer-selectvoicebyhints(system-speech-synthesis-voicegender-system-speech-synthesis-voiceage-system-int32-system-globalization-cultureinfo)): *... a speech synthesis engine that supports that language-country code must be installed.*

Comment: @Clemens yes, I tried that, but, in this case, he voices the given word in three different languages at the same time, and it is necessary that, for example, I choose English culture and he would speak in an English voice, when choosing German culture - in a German voice, and so on

Comment: Do not call it three times.

Comment: @Clemens it didn't work, the voice doesn't change, as the voice of a Russian woman was, and it remains, and she also pronounces English and German words incorrectly (

Comment: solved the problem, inserted the following code into the handler of the application language change event:
`CultureInfo currLang = App.Language;`
`speechSynthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, currLang);`
@Clemens in any case, thank you for your help)

Comment: @samurai_eminovich Please post your solution as a formal answer (instead of a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, inserted the following code into the handler of the application language change event:

```
CultureInfo currLang = App.Language; 
speechSynthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, currLang);
```

Comment: What is `App.Language`?